# XlDirectionDown and selecting filled cells with Python

Tags: python, win32com

I've already asked the root question but I thought I might see if I can get more help with this. I'm trying to work with XlDirectionDown in order to select the last filled cell in an Excel spreadsheet.

Ultimately, I'd like to use Python to select all filled cells in this sheet from A through AE. It will be copied into a text file and appended into SQL Server...so I don't want any blanks.

What I have so far:

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = 1;

excel.Workbooks.Open('G:/working.xlsx')

XlDirectionDown = 4

last = excel.Range("A:A").End(XlDirectionDown)
excel.Range("A1:A"+str(last)).Select()
```

First of all, the XlDirectionDown does not seem to work. The cursor in Excel remains on the first cell.
Secondly, I get an exception for the last line in this code (something to do with Range). Does anybody understand what's going on with this code? Also, is there ANY documentation on win32com or Pywin32 out there?? I can't find any how-to's! Thanks as always everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used a specific cell rather than range of cells as starting point. Replace

```
last = excel.Range("A:A").End(XlDirectionDown)
```

with

```
last = excel.Range("A1:A1").End(XlDirectionDown)
```

However if there are any blank cells, this will stop just before it. You probably want to use `UsedRange()` instead. This will be the smallest range that contains all your cells, *according to Excel*: you may find (as I have) that resulting range is wider than AE (contains blank columns at end), and contains many entirely blank rows at the bottom. However, since you want to filter out blank cells anyways, those will be skipped during filtering.

As to the exception on last line of code, this is because End returns a Range object, and you can't convert a range to a string, or if you can then `str(last)` is a range so `"A1:A"+str(last)` will be an invalid range.

As to filtering out blank cells, I'm not sure what that means: when you copy the data to a text file, what will you put for blank cells? If you have "A blank C" will you put "A C"? The C will end up in wrong column of your database. Anyways just something that caught my attention.

There is no single place for documentation for win32com, although the Python on Windows book has a lot of info, and google gets you results quite useful, including SO hits. The one thing that keeps tripping me whenever I use Excel COM (this is not specific to python's win32com) is that everything in a workbook is a Range, you can't have an individual cells, even when some methods or properties might lead you to think you are getting a cell you're actually getting a range, it often requires a bit of extra thinking about how to go about getting to the desired cell.

Comment: Thanks for the replies Schollii and Olav. I'm close. How exactly can I use a variable as a Range() value?

Comment: Sorry for all the dumb questions. I'll go with UsedRange. ws.UsedRange.Select() works beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got started with win32com and Excel [here](http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/).

In your code, what does `excel.Range("A:A").End(XlDirectionDown)` return? Test it. You might want to add `.Select()`, and then use `excel.Selection.Address` to get the last cell. Test it in interactive mode, it's easier to see what's going on there.

As an alternative, you can use a while loop to go through your cells. This code is looping the rows until an empty cell:

```
excel.Range("A1").Select()
while excel.ActiveCell.Value:
    val = excel.ActiveCell.Value
    print(val)
    excel.ActiveCell.Offset(2,1).Select()  # Move a row down
```

The last line is a bit funny; in VBA you should write `Offset(1,0)` to go one row down. However in Python you have to add one to both row and column. Maybe due to indexing?

Comment: Thanks, Olav. I have last = excel.Range("A1:A1").End(XlDirectionDown).Select() working;  but I need to select ALL the cells from the top to the last cell. How can I use a variable as a value for Range()?